# Pandas ohlc resampling: Getting 00:00:00 time and incorrect date when resampling tick data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ohlc

This is what I'm using to add the data to my tick data frame:

```
dfTick = {
    'time': data['time'],
    'mid': data['mid'],
}

tick = pd.DataFrame(dfTick).set_index('time')
tick.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(tick.index)

current_candle = current_candle.append(tick)
```

This is the tick data in the dataframe:

```
                                         mid
time
2021-04-08 01:37:05.803333138+00:00  0.76097
2021-04-08 01:37:20.152602558+00:00  0.76094
2021-04-08 01:37:53.382876759+00:00  0.76097
2021-04-08 01:37:56.856087693+00:00  0.76094
2021-04-08 01:37:57.148063649+00:00  0.76090
2021-04-08 01:38:16.598799961+00:00  0.76087
2021-04-08 01:38:30.978559522+00:00  0.76092
2021-04-08 01:38:33.302859897+00:00  0.76096
2021-04-08 01:38:43.222445326+00:00  0.76099
2021-04-08 01:39:08.770058921+00:00  0.76104
2021-04-08 01:39:32.495760219+00:00  0.76100
2021-04-08 01:39:32.694723608+00:00  0.76096
2021-04-08 01:39:34.243899267+00:00  0.76099
```

I'm using this to make the candles (I'm making 5min candle and appending it to another frame):

```
current_candle['mid'].resample(5M).ohlc()
```

This is what I'm getting out:

```
                           open     high      low    close
time
2021-04-30 00:00:00+00:00  0.76097  0.76104  0.76087  0.76099
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `current_candle['mid'].resample('5M').ohlc()`, `M` means month. You may want `5min`.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this. This fixed my issue.